# Extracting feature vector from Images Tensorflow OOM

Tags: out-of-memory, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have used pretrained network weights that I have downloaded from Caffe zoo to build a feature extractor (VGG-16) in tensorflow.

I have therefore redefined the architecture of the network in TF with the imported weights as constants and added an extra fully connected layer with tf.Variables to train a linear SVM by SGD on Hinge loss cost.

My initial training set is composed of 100000 32x32x3 images in the form of a numpy array. 
I therefore had to resize them to 224x224x3 which is the input size of VGG but that does not fit into memory.

So I removed unnecessary examples and narrowed it down to 10000x224x224x3 images which is awful but still acceptable as only support vectors are important but even then I still get OOM with TF while training.

That should not be the case as the only important representation is the one from penultimate layer of size 4096 which is easily manageable and the weights to backprop on are of size only (4096+1bias).

So what I can do is first transform all my images to features with TF network with only constants to form a 10000x4096 dataset and then train a second tensorflow model. 
Or at each batch recalculate all features for the batch. In the next_batch method. Or use the panoply of buffers/queue runners that TF provides but it is a bit scary as I am not really familiar with those.

I do not like those method I think there should be something more elegant (without too much queues if possible).

What would be the most Tensorflow-ic method to deal with this ?

Comment: Your images are pretty small, upscaling them so much does not make much sense, training a network on them could be better (or even an autoencoder).

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro You do have a point. Unfortunately I tried to train a network (a few networks in fact) on them from scratch and it proved to be not quite as efficient as I expected due to various reasons. That is why I wanted to try transfer learning.

Comment: You would need to do transfer learning from a network that uses images of similar size. 32x32 color images shouldn't be hard to train to an acceptable accuracy (like 70-80% or more), specially for the amount of data you have. Networks trained on the  CIFAR-10/100 dataset could work much better.

Comment: Even if the resizing seems far-fetched I actually still expect Imagenet trained networks to work better (maybe I will be mistaken?) but of course you are also right I will try with CIFAR too. However that does not answer my question.

Comment: You are right, the solution is just to load one batch of images (32 or so) at a time, but I have no idea how to do that in TensorFlow specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess a way to do that using some queues and threads but not too much would be to save the training set into a tensorflow protobuf format (or several) using `tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter`.

Then creating a method to read and decode a single example from the protobuf and finally use `tf.train.shuffle_batch` to feed BATCH_SIZE examples to the optimizer using the former method.

This way there is only a maximum of capacity (defined in shuffle_batch) tensors in the memory at the same time.

This [awesome tutorial from Indico](https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/) explains it all.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, 100K images are not fitting in memory at all, while 10K images do fit in memory, but then the network itself OOMs. That sounds very reasonable, because 10K images alone, assuming they are represented using 4 bytes per pixel per channel, occupy 5.6GiB of space (or 1.4GiB if you somehow only spend 1 byte per pixel per channel), so even if the dataset happens to fit in memory, as you add your model, that will occupy couple more GiBs, you will OOM.

Now, there are several ways you can address it:

1. You should train using minibatches (if you do not already). With a minibatch if size 512 you will load significantly less data to the GPU. With minibatches you also do not need to load your entire dataset into a numpy array at the beginning. Build your iterator in a way that will load 512 images at a time, run forward and backward pass (`sess.run(train...)`), load next 512 images etc. This way at no point you will need to have 10K or 100K images in memory simultaneously.
2. It also appears to be very wasteful to upscale images, when your original images are so much smaller. What you might consider doing is taking convolution layers from VGG net (dimensions of conv layers do not depend on dimensions of the original images), and train the fully connected layers on top of them from scratch. To do that just trim the VGG net after the flatten layer, run it for all the images you have and produce the output of the flatten layer for each image, then train a three layer fully connected network on those features (this will be relatively fast compared to training the entire conv network), and plug the resulting net after the flatten layer of the original VGG net. This might also produce better results, because the convolution layers are trained to find features in the original size images, not blurry upscaled images.

Comment: Great answer thanks I think the most important part is that you do not need in fact to load the whole array into memory if you train by batch, the solution is indeed to enqueue a certain number of images (far less than the whole dataset but more than batch_size) and dequeue batch_size of them at each step to train your network. Is it what iterators do ? I did just what you described in 1 except that I load the whole dataset into memory and iterate on it.

Comment: I am still thinking about the second part of your answer I will get back to you. However both answers are somehow unsatisfactory because what I wanted to do is similar to what you describe in 2. by setting the weights of the networks to constants in tensorflow you only train relatively few neurones. But that still do not fit in memory gonna try with 1 with 2.

Comment: I am gonna look into iterators as you mentionned.

Comment: According to this [FAQ](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) on python iterators you do need to first load the full object no ?